# Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.30

Tags: cicd, eclipse-memory-analyzer, eclipse-mat

I am trying to build Eclipse-MAT from scratch via source code, version 1.15.0 using Tycho/Maven, facing the following error while downloading maven dependencies :

```
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition file: 
/eclipse-mat/org.eclipse.mat/org.eclipse.mat.targetdef/mat-2023-12.target: 
Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location 
https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.30/: 
Unable to read repository at https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.30. HTTP connect timed out -> [Help 1]
```

Maven command :

```
mvn clean install -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -P skip-ui-tests -P build-release-rcp
```

I tried different ways but didn't work, also didn't find any promising solution for this online.

Please assist me on this issue..
Thanks in advance!